# Qt Application will not compile

Tags: c++, qt, hashtable

This has been stumping me for a while.  I am trying to create a function that takes a hash table, and returns said hash table.  However I am getting this error in the header file,

```
error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope.
error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

Here is the header file itself:

```
#ifndef NAME_SPAWN_H
#define NAME_SPAWN_H
#include <QString>
#include <QHash>
#include <string>

class Name_Spawn
{
public:
    Name_Spawn();
    void initalize();
private:
    QString int_2_str(int);
    void seed();
    QHash<string,QString> setTable(QHash<string,QString>);
};

#endif // NAME_SPAWN_H
```

As you can see, string has been declared.  Any ideas?  I am at my wits end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real name of `string` is `std::string`.  Try using that instead.

(You can leave off the `std::` qualifier only if there's a `using namespace std;` directive in scope.  But it's a good habit not to put `using namespace std;` in header files.)

Comment: I knew I did something stupid.  Thanks a bunch.  I've been out of the C++ world for far too long